# How to import both annotation and yml routes from same bundle at once?

Tags: symfony

My reusable bundle uses 3rd party bundle and its routing file. So my `AppBundle/resources/config/routing.yml` import 3rd party bundle routes

```
3rd_party_bundle_routing:
    resource: "@3rdPartyBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

But how to import my `AppBundle/../routing.yml` in `app/../routing.yml` ?

---

edit:

original `app/../routing.yml` looks like this

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

With multiple resources - not working:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'  
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

So the question is how to import both annotation and yml routes from same bundle at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation    

app_yml:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Comment: what if my bundle need multiple resources? `app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"`

Comment: It doesn't sense at all. Your routing file just will be imported to global router space. So you still can use multiple resources in your bundle's config -- but need to import it only once.

Comment: check my answer please